# How can I set 3 values in spinner

Tags: spinner, javafx-8, fxml, netbeans-8, jspinner

I want time like 02:25:12AM hour,min,sec in one spinner. How can I do that? I have done only for one value like

```
<Spinner fx:id="spinner" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="10.0" initialValue="60"        
         max="120"  prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="60.0" />
```

It shows error like

> jaavaFx.scene.control.Spinner does not support min/max/intial propery

But it works fine. Now I want to do it for 3 values.

Comment: You may use 3 spinners, it is more convenient, since you don't need to "up" click 60 times to add a minute, just 1 clcick on "minute" spinner ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @UlukBiy says in the comments, you probably want to use three spinners here. You probably also want to implement "wrap around", so that if you increment the number of seconds past 59, it resets to 0 and the minutes increment, etc.

Also, to set the min and max, you set them on the `SpinnerValueFactory`, not on the `Spinner` itself. See the Javadocs for [`Spinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html), [`SpinnerValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.html), and [`SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory.html).

Here is a complete example (in FXML):

TimeSpinner.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory ?>

<HBox  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TimeSpinnerController">
    <Spinner fx:id="hourSpinner" prefWidth="60">
        <valueFactory>
            <javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory fx:id="hourValueFactory">
                <min>0</min>
                <max>23</max>
                <wrapAround>true</wrapAround>
            </javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory>
        </valueFactory>
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner fx:id="minuteSpinner" prefWidth="60">
        <valueFactory>
            <javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory fx:id="minuteValueFactory">
                <min>0</min>
                <max>59</max>
                <wrapAround>true</wrapAround>
            </javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory>>
        </valueFactory>
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner fx:id="secondSpinner" prefWidth="60">
        <valueFactory>
            <javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory fx:id="secondValueFactory">
                <min>0</min>
                <max>59</max>
                <wrapAround>true</wrapAround>
            </javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory>>
        </valueFactory>
    </Spinner>
</HBox>
```

TimeSpinnerController:

```
import java.time.Duration;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;



public class TimeSpinnerController {

    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> hourSpinner ;
    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> minuteSpinner ;
    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> secondSpinner ;

    private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Duration> time = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

    public void initialize() {
        minuteSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (oldValue.intValue() == 59 && newValue.intValue() == 0) {
                hourSpinner.increment();
            }
            if (oldValue.intValue() == 0 && newValue.intValue() == 59) {
                hourSpinner.decrement();
            }
        });

        secondSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (oldValue.intValue() == 59 && newValue.intValue() == 0) {
                minuteSpinner.increment();
            }
            if (oldValue.intValue() == 0 && newValue.intValue() == 59) {
                minuteSpinner.decrement();
            }
        });

        time.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(this::computeTime, hourSpinner.valueProperty(),
                minuteSpinner.valueProperty(), secondSpinner.valueProperty()));
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Duration> timeProperty() {
        return time.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
    }

    public Duration getTime() {
        return timeProperty().get();
    }

    private Duration computeTime() {
        int seconds = secondSpinner.getValue();
        int minutes = minuteSpinner.getValue();
        int hours = hourSpinner.getValue();
        int totalSeconds = (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60 + seconds ;
        return Duration.ofSeconds(totalSeconds);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TimeSpinnerTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TimeSpinner.fxml"));
        HBox timeSpinner = loader.load();
        TimeSpinnerController timeController = loader.getController() ;
        Label label = new Label();

        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            long s = timeController.getTime().getSeconds() ;
            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", s / 3600, (s / 60) % 60, s % 60);
        }, timeController.timeProperty()));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, timeSpinner, label);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(24));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: In fxml it shows error "Instance of /javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory can not created by FXML Loader."

Comment: although It runs well but when i set location value it doesn't shows effect  <Spinner fx:id="minuteSpinner" prefWidth="60" layoutX="500.0" layoutY="10.0" >

Comment: You get that error when loading the FXML, or just in SceneBuilder? The FXML Loader is pretty horrible when trying to work with nested classes; I haven't tried with scene builder. I don't understand your second comment. What do you mean "it doesn't show effect"?

Comment: i worked with scene builder.I want to change position of spinner by default it take (0,0) in parent panel.so in second comment i changed x and y for changing location but it doesn't work.

Comment: Setting the layout properties won't have any effect on something in an `HBox`. You could set the layout properties of the `HBox`; whether or not that has an effect depends on its parent. But this is a question about layout, it is independent of your original question.

Comment: If the error message is from SceneBuilder, then that is a SceneBuilder bug.

Comment: Yes right i have to set HBox location and it works no bug in SceneBuilder. thank you :)